# Another word for roadie / backstage staff for a rock band?

Tags: synonyms

I’ve seen a word once and I just cannot recall the word. the word I’m in search for means a group of staffs that move along and travel with the band they are assisting.

I googled “roadie synonyms” and there was nothing I was looking for. ( or I just couldn’t recognize it, this is the worst )

Please help me find, recall the word. Please suggest me any words that relevant to the meaning I mentioned above.

Comment: Questions of the form *What is the word I can't remember?* are poor questions. We can't just throw out multiple synonyms until we stumble on the one that you'd been thinking of. If we are to provide a single word that clearly fits, you need to give specific, objective criteria. (Something that doesn't rely on reading your mind, but which can be reasonably and objectively determined.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One word is ***entourage:***

> A group of people attending or surrounding an important person.
>
> > ‘The whole city was taken over: stars and their entourages occupied the best suites in hotels and booked out the top restaurants.’
> >
> > ‘These are the entourages that follow important people around, made up of advisors, heralds, messengers and servants.’
>
> — [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/entourage)

However, *entourage* generally means the important people who are closest to the principal; perhaps a manager or publicist for a rock band. The road crew who shift equipment wouldn't (I think) usually be included.

Comment: ...OK, but please do consider my last sentence.